# Take Broadcast program

Tags: php, html, json

I have a channel publishing sites and I wanna get into the channel CNN broadcast program..

CNN broadcast the program here: (you can see in source)

http://edition.cnn.com//CNNI/schedules/json/CSI.EU.html

How the data according to the time of withdrawal?

*For example*

```
    Now program: "overflow's table"
    next program: "stack's table" in 30 minute
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible:

```
<?php

$html = file_get_contents('http://edition.cnn.com//CNNI/schedules/json/CSI.EU.html');

preg_match('#<textarea id="jsCode">(.*)</textarea>#is', $html, $matches);

$json = trim($matches[1]);
$json = str_replace("'", '"', $json);
$json = preg_replace('#([\w]+): ("|\[)#is', '"\\1": \\2', $json);

$json = json_decode($json, TRUE);

$startTimeUnix = time();
foreach($json['airings'] as $key => $value)
{
  if ($value['startTimeUnix'] > $startTimeUnix)
    break;
}

echo 'Now: ' , $json['airings'][$key]['programName'];   # CNN Newsroom
echo 'Next: ', $json['airings'][++$key]['programName']; # World Sport
```

Comment: Waow! Thank you so much!! You are king! Thank you! but Can you get two hour forward time?

Comment: @Saracoglu should be easy, just modify `$startTimeUnix` as `$startTimeUnix = time() + 7200;`, 7200 seconds equals 2 hours. Thanks.