# Take TV program with XML

Tags: php, xml

I have a channel publishing sites and I wanna get into the channel CNN broadcast program. CNN broadcast the program here (you can see in source - XML file):

```
http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/cnn.info/weekly_cnn.info_tvprofil.net.xml
```

How the data according to the time of withdrawal?

For example:

```
Now program: "bitmez's table"
next program: "stack's table" in 30 minute
```

Is this possible?

**Update 1:**

I can take the XML data but to all of XML file-

```
<?php

$url = 'http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/cnn.info/weekly_cnn.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
if (!$xml) {
    trigger_error('XML file -- read error',E_USER_ERROR);
    return;
}

foreach ($xml as $programme) {
    echo 'Now: ', $programme->title, "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: It does not make much sense to ask "Is it possible" on Stackoverflow because the answer most certainly is: *"Yes"* and then you're as far as you were before asking the question. Instead try to explain what exactly you try to do and what makes it hard for you to achieve it. Name which criteria there are for the "now program" and which there are for the "next program" and how both relate to each other. The connection of data often is the key to an answer for such kind of questions.

Comment: @hakre Thank you for your help! Thanks!! How can you do the timing? For example: "Now: hakre's table".. There are start time and finish time in the XML file.. Starting time will be released the names of the programs, How is this done?

Comment: Time is always relative. So it starts with finding the place that says what now actually is.

Comment: @hakre the "start" tag and the server time together program-time in XML file.. I want you to write you a small code for this time, please take the time to at least

Comment: @hakre http://pastebin.com/Grva12sQ  - Can it be done with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php

$url = 'weekly_cnn.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

$now = new DateTime('now');
$it  = new IteratorIterator($xml->programme);

foreach ($it as $programm)
{
  $start = DateTime::createFromFormat('YmdHis', $programm['start']);
  if ($start > $now)
    break;      
}

echo 'Now: ', $programme->title;
$it->next();
if ($it->valid) {
    echo 'Next: ', $it->current()->title;
}
```

[off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) Please, don't email me with requests, just because I answered your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19420871/take-broadcast-program), doesn't mean I need to do it again. It's basically the same, learn by using manual, for your own sake. Cheeers.

Comment: I'm checking it now! You are a KING!:)

Comment: Many thanks again, How to auto-refresh can be done? without page-refresh. Is it possible renewal of 30 minutes?

Comment: @bitmez4 It's possible with XHR or cron job depending on context.

Comment: Is there this page? http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call -- Recommend page for me, please.. I will do it myself:) Your suggest to me a document/page

Comment: Where there is error? Please check; http://pastebin.com/tF3pMyna -- I'm going to do this

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the attributes and compare them

```
$url   = 'http://tvprofil.net/xmltv/data/cnn.info/weekly_cnn.info_tvprofil.net.xml';
$array = (array) simplexml_load_file($url);

// FLATTEN THE RESULT SET
$programmes = array();
foreach ($array as $k => $v)
{
    if ($k == 'programme'){
        foreach($v as $p)
        {
            $programmes[] = (array) $p;
        }
        break;
    }
}

$tim = time();
$now = array();
$nex = array();

foreach ($programmes as $show)
{
    $attr = $show['@attributes'];
    if ($tim >= $attr['start'] && $tim <= $attr['stop'])
    {
        // GETS THE CURRENT SHOW
        $now = $show;
    }
}

print_r($now);
```

Comment: Thank you, butthe program name is not on the screen

Comment: Written them on the screen: http://img845.imageshack.us/img845/5417/1zkg.png  -- the program does not print the names, title tag required? -- I know I am getting your time

Comment: The is no need to introduce curl when PHP can open that link. There is no need to cast to an array when simeplxml is an XML parser already. -1  because the later could not be edited out quickly.